# 404 on reload with vue-router and Ingress-Nginx

Tags: vue.js, nginx, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have a single web page application in Vue.js which has 3 menus.
Using the vue-router the url changes from `/` to :

- `/users`
- `/groups`
- `/teams`

**When on any of thoses pages if I hit ctrl + R I'll get a 404.**

## What I have

This is my original Ingress:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-signin: https://$host/oauth2/start?rd=$escaped_request_uri
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-url: https://$host/oauth2/auth
  name: my-ing-oauth2-proxy
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: myhost.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: myservice
            port:
              number: 8080
        path: /
        pathType: Prefix
```

This produces 404 on `/users` etc

## What I have tried

I tried multiple annotations

- rewrite-target
- app-root
- use-regex
  Each time aiming to redirect all routes toward `/`. All failed with white pages, 404 etc.

## What kind of works but isn't perfect...

In the end I made a second ingress which deals with the routes I mentionned and then redirects the user to `/`.
It's working but there are 2 issues with this :

- I now have two ingresses (even more as I use oauth2-proxy...)
- I have to hardcode the path as I can't find a way to match all routes
- - Using a regex like `/.+` isn't working

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-signin: https://$host/oauth2/start?rd=$escaped_request_uri
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-url: https://$host/oauth2/auth
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/permanent-redirect: https://myhost.com  # <= here
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
  name: my-ing-oauth2-proxy-routes
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: myhost.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: myservice
            port:
              number: 8080
        path: /groups
        pathType: Prefix
      - backend:
          service:
            name: myservice
            port:
              number: 8080
        path: /teams
        pathType: Prefix
      - backend:
          service:
            name: myservice
            port:
              number: 8080
        path: /users
        pathType: Prefix
```

## What I would like

I would like all routes (`/*`) to redirect to `/` using one ingress.
If it's not possible at least find a way to have the second ingress to match all possible routes instead of hardcoding them. We only have three but it's still a very bad solution.

Using

- nginx : 2.4.1
- ingress-nginx helm chart : nginx-ingress-0.15.1
- Kubernetes : 1.24.3

Thx